# Javascript : CryptoJS object missing SHA1 method

Tags: javascript, sha1, cryptojs

This should be easy to solve....

My CryptoJS object exists, but it doesn't have a SHA1 method.

What do I have to do to make this work? There are many many samples out there. Mine, of course, doesn't work...

The .enc.Hex.stringify method DOES exist...

Any help appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        link href="blaw blaw blaw" rel="stylesheet" >
    </head>
    <body>
        content blaw blaw blaw

       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/core.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/enc-hex.js"></script>
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/hmac-sha1.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript">

           var StringToSign = "blaw blaw blaw";
           var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(StringToSign); // <--- No SHA1 method!

           var result = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(hash);
           $(".content .z-value").html(result);
        </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: SHA1 is already not secure. Use SHA2 or SHA3.

Comment: Really?  Please consider that I MUST use SHA1. Your comment is not helpful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to include sha1.js before loading hmac-sha1.js, because it doesn't load it automatically (at least not in the browser). The same is true for hmac.js. Also, enc-hex.js is already included in core.js.

Example code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="content"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/core.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/hmac.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/3.1.9-1/sha1.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

       var StringToSign = "blaw blaw blaw";
       var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(StringToSign);

       var result = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.stringify(hash);
       $(".content").html(result);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That did it. The snippet in the fiddle I copied used an older version of the scripts, and it only needed script links to hmac-sha1.js and hex.js... Good to have this working, thanks!

Comment: Btw, I just fixed the ordering if you want to use HMAC-SHA1.

Comment: it frustrates me that I have to use old security tech that was officially deprecated. You work with companies that say they are secure and are the best at what they do...then you start to work with their API and find that they haven't upgraded to the common level of what's considered secure... grrr

Comment: Artjom B - yeah, I copied this version this morning - didn't have a chance until now

Comment: "Officially" is a strong term for something that is used anywhere in the world. Yes, SHA-1 is not secure for many use cases anymore. Whether this is true in your case, I don't know. Have a look at [crypto.se] to see if this is the case.

Comment: The RFC says it's superseded; that's official enough. Any PCI implementation is way beyond it and you'll never be certified if you employ it. I'd say it's official as it's a big no-no in any consulting firm to even consider it. Any hacker with reasonable resources will defeat it...well, they wouldn't be a hacker if they couldn't. There are no use cases for it, just as there are no use cases for Windows 95. Sure you can use it, but it's foolish _if you need to be secure_.