# Uncaught ReferenceError: sha1 is not defined

Tags: javascript, sha1

I get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: sha1 is not defined. How can I fix this
I know I have to use an external library just like [Javascript : CryptoJS object missing SHA1 method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45643078/javascript-cryptojs-object-missing-sha1-method)
Here they have used Cryptojs I need in sha1

Answer (score -1):

www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html
I used this library as an external javascript